# Semantics of setting prototype on declared vars in TypeScript definition files

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

## Summary

I've been working on updating some type declarations in DefinitelyTyped (WebXR, but not really a necessary detail) and I'm confused about the semantic difference between certain ways of defining classes, especially when those classes are not directly instantiable and can only be instantiated from within the runtime, returned by DOM API call.

What's the best way to create type definitions for existing classes in the Web API, given that some can be directly instantiated while others cannot? What is the purpose of defining the prototype field in a `declare var` block?

### Question 1: `declare var` vs `declare class`

Specifically, given the following interfaces:

```js
interface ClassInstantiable {
    something: any;
}

interface ClassNotInstantiable {
    something: any;
}
```

I don't understand the difference between using `declare var`:

```js
declare var ClassInstantiable: {
    new(): ClassInstantiable;
    prototype: ClassInstantiable;
};

declare var ClassNotInstantiable: {
    prototype: ClassNotInstantiable;
}
```

... and `declare class`:

```js
declare class ClassInstantiable implements ClassInstantiable { }

declare abstract class ClassNotInstantiable implements ClassNotInstantiable { }
```

It's pretty clear that the `interface` is necessary, lest someone in a downstream project wants to extend the definition within their own project.

Actually, I do understand one particular difference between the two styles. With the `declare var` syntax, anything defining a constructor seems completely equivalent in type checking operations to `declare class`. But while not defining a constructor in `declare var` makes it not instantiable, it also makes it not possible to use `instanceof` to type inspect instances of the class, whereas `declare abstract class` seems to hit the exact features I want.

### Question 2: purpose of the `prototype` field in `declare var`

Additionally, I tried a number of iterations of different declarations to see how the type checker would respond, which has made me realize that I don't understand the purpose of the `prototype` field in the `declare var` option.

|  | `new`-able | `instanceof`-able |
| --- | --- | --- |
| declare var w/ constructor and prototype | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| declare var w/ constructor | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| declare var w/ prototype | ❌ | ❌ |
| declare var (no constructor or prototype) | ❌ | ❌ |
| declare abstract class | ❌ | ✔️ |
| declare class | ✔️ | ✔️ |

In lib.d.ts, there are no instances of `declare class` or `declare abstract class` of any kind.

There's a curious example in `Audio` vs `HTMLAudioElement`. `Audio` is defined without any interface, just a **declare var w/ constructor and prototype**. `Audio` is instantiable and values returned by it (HTMLAudioElement values) can be type tested with `instanceof` against both `Audio` and `HTMLAudioElement`.

But `HTMLAudioElement` is implemented with an interface *and* **declare var w/ constructor**.  When the type checker runs, it doesn't balk at trying to call `new HTMLAudioElement();`. I mean, it shouldn't, the type definition says it should be fine. But at runtime, it's an error, as `HTMLAudioElement` is an invalid constructor. So I actually think this is a mistake.

Regardless, I wasn't able to figure out what the purpose of the prototype field was in the `declare var` options I tested.